# appcmd.exe to list IIS config section attribute is returning an ERROR message:Unknown attribute

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-8, appcmd

I am running this command as admin in elevated prompt:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list config "website" /section:requestFiltering /text:AllowDoubleEscaping
```

It returns error message: ERROR (message:Unknown attribute ""AllowDoubleEscaping"". Replace with -? for help.)

So I next ran the following command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -?
```

It returned this output and yes, I can see that the allowDoubleEscaping is missing

```
ERROR ( message:-allowHighBitCharacters
-unescapeQueryString
-removeServerHeader
-fileExtensions.allowUnlisted
-fileExtensions.applyToWebDAV
-fileExtensions.[fileExtension='string'].fileExtension
-fileExtensions.[fileExtension='string'].allowed
-requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength
-requestLimits.maxUrl
-requestLimits.maxQueryString
-requestLimits.headerLimits.[header='string'].header
-requestLimits.headerLimits.[header='string'].sizeLimit
-verbs.allowUnlisted
-verbs.applyToWebDAV
-verbs.[verb='string'].verb
-verbs.[verb='string'].allowed
-hiddenSegments.applyToWebDAV
-hiddenSegments.[segment='string'].segment
-alwaysAllowedUrls.[url='string'].url
-alwaysAllowedQueryStrings.[queryString='string'].queryString
-denyUrlSequences.[sequence='string'].sequence
-denyQueryStringSequences.[sequence='string'].sequence
-filteringRules.[name='string'].name
-filteringRules.[name='string'].scanUrl
-filteringRules.[name='string'].scanQueryString
-filteringRules.[name='string'].scanAllRaw
-filteringRules.[name='string'].denyUnescapedPercent
-filteringRules.[name='string'].scanHeaders.[requestHeader='string'].requestHeader
-filteringRules.[name='string'].appliesTo.[fileExtension='string'].fileExtension
-filteringRules.[name='string'].denyStrings.[string='string'].string
```

So which files is appcmd actually checking for these?  I went ahead and checked the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml file and it does have this attribute defined in there.  This seems to be the only place this is defined, so I am confused where else its not finding this attribute to throw the error??

```
<sectionSchema name="system.webServer/security/requestFiltering">
    <attribute name="allowDoubleEscaping" type="bool" defaultValue="false" />
    <attribute name="allowHighBitCharacters" type="bool" defaultValue="true" />
    <attribute name="unescapeQueryString" type="bool" defaultValue="true" />
```

Comment: This link should help you: [https://blogs.iis.net/eokim/understanding-appcmd-exe-list-set-config-configurationpath-section-name-parameter-name-value](https://blogs.iis.net/eokim/understanding-appcmd-exe-list-set-config-configurationpath-section-name-parameter-name-value).

Comment: @samwu Thank you. I saw this link, but still doesn't explain where appcmd is looking and not finding the schema element allowDoubleEscaping.  As I show above, my IIS_schema.xml document DOES have this element.

Comment: I think the properties of object `AllowDoubleEscaping` do not apply to object `config`.